# Identifying repeat tickets in Excel with ifs, index, match, nested if, countifs

Tags: excel, indexing, nested, match, ifs

I am having fits with an excel formula I just cant figure out and sometimes more than one set of eyes can make short work of a problem. I have been chasing google results for many hours on this, so here I am finally begging for help.

One workbook with two tabs. Tab "import_1" contains imported data and is simply the account number (column A, accountNum), and the date the ticket was created (column B, Date_Created). Tab "import_2" contains imported data as well and is simply the account number (column A, accountNum), the date the second ticket was created (column B, Date_Created) and then the helper column that contains the unknown solution to my question (column C, Repeat_?).

Tab name "import_1":

```
accountNum   | Date_Created
-------------|-------------
10000001     | 24-APR-2023 12:04:00 AM
10000002     | 25-APR-2023 12:04:00 AM
10000003     | 25-APR-2023 12:04:00 AM
10000004     | 25-APR-2023 12:04:00 AM
10000005     | 25-APR-2023 12:04:00 AM
```

Tab name "import_2":

```
accountNum   | Date_Created           | REPEAT_?
-------------|------------------------|----
10000001     | 04/23/2023 12:01:00 AM | No
10000001     | 04/24/2023 12:01:00 AM | No
10000001     | 04/24/2023 12:04:00 AM | Yes
10000001     | 04/24/2023 10:41:00 PM | Yes
10000005     | 04/29/2023 12:10:00 AM | Yes
```

The question is that I need to identify REPEAT tickets that are created by accountNum. The rules for what is a repeat are simple;

1. accountNum on tab "import_2" has to also be found on tab "import_1"
2. those accountNum's from tab "import_2" that are actually found on tab "import_1" then need to have thier date/time stamped at the same date/time or after from tab "import_1". If those two conditions are met then we have a 'Yes', if not then a 'No'. Yes obviously means it is a repeat ticket because it was created for the same account after the first ticket was created and no means it is not a repeat because the second ticket was created before the first ticket was.

Helper columns can be added if it will get us to a solution, but some sort of fancy formula in tab "import_2" column C would be the best result. I have tried: if, ifs, countif, countifs, nested if, index/match and I cannot get any to work. Some of those work fine for the first part in identifying the duplicate account numbers but when I try to include the equal to or after (for Date_Created) is where it all goes to crud. Your expertise and help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Tab 'import_2" cell C3 corrected to No

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried?

Comment: What is your excel version?, please add it as part of the tag list, if you have any Excel version constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more than a "fancy formula" here.

It seems you have neither fully, nor carefully, specified the conditions for whether a ticket is a repeat. The 2 conditions you've spelled out would indicate that the 2nd ticket on import_2 is NOT a repeat.

```
10000001 | 04/24/2023 12:01:00 AM | Yes
```

That's because it does not repeat a ticket on import_1, as your specified conditions require. But your sample declares that it is a repeat, presumably because it repeats the ticket above it on import_2.

If my interpretation is correct, you need a condition that tests whether a ticket on import_2 duplicates another ticket on import_2, in addition to the two conditions you've provided. This gets complicated because it requires mixing both `AND` and `OR` conditions. Excel's `COUNTIFS()` statement doesn't allow `OR` conditions.

One possibility is using two `COUNTIFS()`, one for each tab, to handle the `OR`. I've kept them in separate columns to help keep it clear. The first column checks for a repeat of a ticket on import_1, the second does the same test on import_2.

```
D2:  =COUNTIFS(import_1!$A$2:$A$6, import_2!A2, import_1!$C$2:$C$6, "<" & import_2!C2)
```

```
E2:  =COUNTIFS(import_2!$A$2:$A$6, import_2!A2, import_2!$C$2:$C$6, "<" & import_2!C2)
```

The REPEAT? column sums those two formulas; if `SUM > 0` then you have a repeat:

```
F2:  =IF(D2 + E2 > 0, "Yes", "No")
```

I've converted both datetime columns to values (Column C on both tabs) just to avoid any issues with Excel seeing them as text instead of datetimes:

```
C2:  =DATEVALUE(B2) + TIMEVALUE(B2)
```

That might be why it "all goes to crud" when you compare the dates. Another point is that your condition 2 says created AFTER the first ticket, but your text says "equal to or after" (that's why I said you haven't "carefully" specified the conditions). My formulas go with AFTER, per your stated conditions.

And as @cybernetic_nomad said, it's always good to spell out what you've already tried.

Tab import_2:

[image: Tab import_2]

Comment: I think I overcomplicated it and confused myself in my post here. I apologize for that. You got close but not exactly right. I was only looking to see if the account number from 'import_2' is also found on 'import_1' and if it is, is the timestamp for it on 'import_2' greater than or equal to the timestamp on 'import_1'. If both conditions are met then the accountNum on 'import_2' is a repeat....

Comment: ... Simplifying at as such I was able to solve it on my own by using index/match to check the accountNum and return the timestamp from 'import_1' to a helper column in 'import_2' and then a easy if statement with '>=' to compare the two timestamps to determine if it was before, same, or after. Problem solved now.

Comment: Correcting cell C3 from Yes to No makes my main point irrelevant, although it's still a useful reference for ```OR``` conditions. But my second point remains valid. Excel, and logic in general, are unforgiving when we're careless. (Yes, I've learned the hard way!)